# VBA - Manipulate Specific Sheet Data With Macro - Not Activesheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10 sheets in a workbook - These sheets were imported from individual workbooks - These workbooks were extracts from different monitoring tools

I need to apply a filter across all 10 worksheets, however, not all the sheets are in the same format/structure.

With 6 of the worksheets, the column headers are the same and in the same order.

The remaining 4 sheets have different headers. For example: The filter needs to look for a header name *Status* - This works for the 6 sheets that have the same structure, however, the other 4 sheets have the following:

**wsheet1:**

*User Status* instead of **Status** - I need to change the header to **Status**

**wsheet2:**

*Current_Status* instead of **Status** - I need to change the header to **Status**

Below is sample code that is supposed to manipulate the **specified sheet** in in order to have it "look" the same as the others, however, I am having some really annoying issues where the code isn't applied to the sheet specified and is instead applied to the "Activesheet" when the macro is executed.

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub arrangeSheets()

    Dim lastCol As Long, idCount As Long, nameCount As Long, headerRow As Long

    Dim worksh As Integer, WS_Count As Integer, i As Integer, count As Integer

    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, rngData As Range

    Dim worksheetexists As Boolean

            worksh = Application.Sheets.count
            worksheetexists = False

            headerRow = 1       'row number with headers
            lastCol = Cells(headerRow, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column in header row
            idCount = 1
            nameCount = 1


            ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
            ' workbook.
            WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

            'If Application.Match finds no match it will throw an error so we need to skip them
            On Error Resume Next

            For x = 1 To worksh

                If Worksheets(x).Name = "wsheet1" Then
                    worksheetexists = True

                    Set rng = Sheets("wsheet1").Range(Cells(headerRow, 1), Cells(headerRow, lastCol)) 'header range

                    With Worksheets("wsheet1").Name

                        Rows(2).Delete
                        Rows(1).Delete
                        count = Application.Match("*USER STATUS*", Worksheets("wsheet1").Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

                        If Not IsError(count) Then
                            For Each cel In rng                     'loop through each cell in header
                                If cel = "*USER STATUS*" Then       'check if header is "Unit ID"

                                    cel = "STATUS" & idCount        'rename "Unit ID" using idCount
                                    idCount = idCount + 1           'increment idCount

                                End If
                            Next cel
                        End If

                    End With

            Exit For

                End If

            Next x
            End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying that all you need to do is change `User Status` to `Status  on  `wsheet1` and change `Current_Status` to `Status` on `wsheet2`?

Comment: Is this all running in the same workbook? Note the first thing to sort is not to use just Cells or Range and use the worksheet name that goes with them or it will default to Activesheet

Comment: I need to do a few more changes to the 4 worksheets, but I need help on how to "focus" on the correct worksheet then i will work on the code I need to manipulate the sheet.@ashleedawg

Comment: Thank you for your reply @QHarr, im still learning so I will educate myself a little more on these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same headers across all sheets in the workbook you could just copy the headers from the first sheet and paste them on each sheet.

This wouldn't work if your column order is different across sheets, but from the example you gave it's just renaming columns rather than re-ordering?

```
Sub CorrectHeaders()

    Dim cpyRng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Worksheets.count > 1 Then

            With .Worksheets(1)
                Set cpyRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft))
            End With

            .Sheets.FillAcrossSheets cpyRng

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

If the column headers are in different orders, but you just want to replace any cell that contains the text "Status" with just "Status" then you could use `Replace`.  You may want to add an extra condition of `MatchCase:=True`.

```
Sub Correct_Status()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*Status*", Replacement:="Status", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help @Darren. I apologize, in my question I forgot to say that I have a few changes that need to be done, not just renaming the headers. Otherwise your code would have worked perfectly, but on the four sheets that have different headers, they also have a different amount of columns and not in the same order as the other 6 sheets.

Comment: I've added code to replace _Status_.  This won't give you a count on the end of the word though.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. Unfortunately the code does not seem to do anything @Darren. I even created a new workbook with just the column headers in it and tested, but nothing happened.

Comment: That's odd.  My test workbook has six sheet with various cells containing the text "Status":  "Current_Status", "User Status", "This Status is wrong" and "inconcievablestatus's" and it changed each one to just "Status".  The code is in the workbook containing the text to be changed - `ThisWorkbook` and the headers are on row 1?  Maybe try changing `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Ahhh! There we go! Thank you Darren for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

- Consider using `.`, in the `With-End with` section to refer to the Worksheet mentioned:

[image]

- The `Like` in `If cel Like "*USER STATUS*"` works with the `*`, thus will be evaluated to `True` for `12USER STATUS12` or anything similar.
- The `count` variable should be declared as variant, thus it can keep "errors" in itself.

This is how the code could look like:

```
With Worksheets("wsheet1")

    .Rows(2).Delete
    .Rows(1).Delete
    Count = Application.Match("*USER STATUS*", .Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

    If Not IsError(Count) Then
        For Each cel In Rng                     'loop through each cell in header
            If cel Like "*USER STATUS*" Then    'check if header is "Unit ID"
                cel = "STATUS" & idCount        'rename "Unit ID" using idCount
                idCount = idCount + 1           'increment idCount    
            End If
        Next cel
    End If

End With
```

Comment: I amended my code with the sample you provided above @Vityata but nothing is happening on any of the sheets at the moment.

Comment: I also changed the count declaration to variant as @QHarr suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have additional solution which has also helped with this issue. Code below:

```
Sub ManipulateSheets()

    Dim worksh As Integer

    Dim worksheetexists As Boolean

    worksh = Application.Sheets.count
    worksheetexists = False

    'If Application.Match finds no match it will throw an error so we need to skip them
    On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets("wSheet1").Activate

    With Worksheets("wSheet1")

        .Rows(2).Delete
        .Rows(1).Delete
    End With

    Worksheets("wSheet2").Activate

    With Worksheets("wSheet2")

        .Rows(2).Delete

    End With

End Sub
```